# SVG not working

Tags: svg

I have a page where you can create a SVG and download it, but when I download the file I get this message when trying to open it:

This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

The code that is generated is this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?> 
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg height="512" width="512">
    <circle fill-opacity="1" fill="#655f65" r="256" cy="256" cx="256"></circle>
</svg>
```

Any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a namespace (for example `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"`) to the root `svg` tag:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?> 
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  height="512" width="512">
    <circle fill-opacity="1" fill="#655f65" r="256" cy="256" cx="256"></circle>
</svg>
```